# java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I have set up a dynamic web project in Eclipse with a Tomcat 5.5 installation.
Can anyone help me with the below exception .I have configure the build path (servlet.api and ojdbc6.jar)

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
    oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:447)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:951)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:513)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:227)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:531)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:195)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CStatement.java:876)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:1175)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1296)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeQuery(OracleStatement.java:1498)
    oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OracleStatementWrapper.java:406)
    org.apache.jsp.NewFile1_jsp._jspService(NewFile1_jsp.java:66)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:98)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:331)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:329)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:265)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
```

Comment: What part exactly of the error message "table or view does not exist" didn't you understand?

Comment: You've used the wrong table name in your query, or you're connected as a user that isn't the owner of the table - and that user doesn't have permission on the table, or you haven't prefixed it with the owning schema. As you haven't shown the query or any other relevant information it's had to guess which.

Answer (score 0):

It means you don't have the table for the data you want to store. First create the table having the required property, then try to run your program.